# run object scala in databricks

Tags: scala, databricks

I am trying to execute sample code on databricks in scala. It is an object.

```
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val res = for (a <- args) yield a.toUpperCase
    println("Arguments: " + res.toString)
  }
}
```

When I run on databricks; it says 'object defined main'. I am not sure how to execute it now or what is the code to execute it. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are working with is kind of scala REPL. Basically "main" function does not have any significance over there. Having said that you can run your function as follows

```
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val res = for (a <- args) yield a.toUpperCase
    println(res)
    println("Arguments: " + res.toString)
  }
}

Main.main(Array("123","23123"))
```

As is you can call Object Main's main method.

Comment: What about running from a different Notebook? With Comm Edition?

Answer (score 1):

You can call the `main` method in the `Main` object as follows:

```
val args: Array[String] = Array("test1", "test2", "test3")
Main.main(args)
```

What you have in your main method won't print what you expect, which I assume is the values contained in the `res` array. To accomplish that you would need to change it to something like the following:

```
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val res = for (a <- args) yield a.toUpperCase
    println("Arguments: " + res.mkString(" "))
  }
}
```

Comment: Just use a List.